# TF Listener for static transforms exclusively

Tags: ros, c++, tf2-ros, tf-listener, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to listen to only the *static* transforms in a TF tree (e.g. `base_link --> base_laser_link`) without instantiating an entire `tf::TransformListener` object, which *"receives and buffers all coordinate frames that are broadcasted in the system"* ? Can `tf::MessageFilter`s be used for something like that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247944/tf-listener-for-static-transforms-exclusively/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-11-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The static transformations are published on /tf_static, so just listen to them. But as you care about bandwidth, you should have a look at the tf2_ros buffer_server. This node listens to /tf and /tf_static and runs an action server that you can use to get transformations so that your node does not listen to /tf(_static) but only asks the buffer_server if it needs a transformation.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-12**:
Thanks for the quick reply! I'll take a look and get back to you with any follow-up questions :-)

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-11-12**:
OK, so it looks like your answer makes total sense. But I'll have to migrate to `tf2_ros` from `tf` (which I should have done ages ago anyway ...) Thanks again

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-12**:
Moving from tf to tf2 is rather easy. In tf there isn't even a concept of a static transform.

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-07-25**:
Additional question: I have a `tf2_ros::Buffer tf_buffer_` and ask for trafos with `tf_buffer_.lookupTransform()`. How can I be sure a transformation is from /tf_static?